# Can someone please tell me the names of these sound effects and where I can find them?

Tags: sound-effects, sound, request

I found some sounds from the TV Show "Deal or No Deal" and I was wondering where I can find the full, clean versions of the sounds.

The sound when the contestant accepts the deal: https://send.firefox.com/download/6a98f61d7a10eded/#sVMo3CT638C6RXJZD6XhnA

And

The sound when the contestant closes the box to decline the offer: https://send.firefox.com/download/6630068fc2954f5c/#WlBBP6dGkWhF2C4I4svjJA

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ask the TV company - Endemol, now [Endemol Shine](https://www.endemolshinegroup.com) - that way you'll not only get the correct sounds (there were maybe 50 international versions of the show, idk if they all used the same stings), but also be able to arrange proper licensing.

Comment: Neither link works for me.  "This link has expired."